# How to compile nana into static lib

Tags: c++, c++11, makefile, nana

i downloaded nana c++ gui library. 
I'm trying to compile this library, under windows.

I'm using this tutorial:
[nanapro.org - Installing nana](http://nanapro.org/en-us/help/instl_lib_doc.htm)

> Step Two: Create a static linkage library solution within a IDE which
>   you use, and add all the files which are placed in "NanaPath/source"
>   and in its all sub directiories to the solution. Then compile the
>   solution and you will get a static linkage file NanaStatic in the path
>   "NanaPath/build/bin/IDEName".

But my output is:

```
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .clean-conf
make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/user/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppStaticLibrary_1'
rm -f -r build/Debug
rm -f dist/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/libcppstaticlibrary_1.a
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/user/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppStaticLibrary_1'


CLEAN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2s)

"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/user/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppStaticLibrary_1'
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/libcppstaticlibrary_1.a
make[2]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/user/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppStaticLibrary_1'
mkdir -p build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/_ext/2108599812
rm -f build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/_ext/2108599812/any.o.d
g++    -c -g -I../../nana/include -std=c++11 -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/_ext/2108599812/any.o.d -o build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/_ext/2108599812/any.o ../../nana/source/any.cpp
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:75: recipe for target 'build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/_ext/2108599812/any.o' failed
make[2]: *** [build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/_ext/2108599812/any.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/user/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppStaticLibrary_1'
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:66: recipe for target '.build-conf' failed
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/user/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppStaticLibrary_1'
nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: recipe for target '.build-impl' failed
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2


BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 1s)
```

Comment: That `g++` command should have generated an error if it failed but I don't see it in that output. Where did that `Makefile-Debug.mk` come from? Can you run that `g++` command manually? Does it work? Does it error?

Answer (score 0):

Nana evolves very fast. Currently compile only with C++11.
I recommend you download the release version at:

[Nana - A modern C++ GUI library / Sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/nanapro/files/)

Or better, with the last fixes at [GitHub](https://github.com/cnjinhao/nana):

[Nana Hotfixes](https://github.com/cnjinhao/nana/archive/hotfixes-1.0.1.zip)

The installation is very simple. Basically you copy the source code of nana (which is tiny: 0.5 MB in zip) and tell your build system where it is. Follow the links for detailed information.

- At the [Wiki](https://github.com/qPCR4vir/nana-docs/wiki/Installation)
- At the [Project site](http://nanapro.org/en-us/help/instl_lib_doc.htm)